# what module does CdkTableModule actually live in?

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I was following an example on Medium.com

https://medium.com/tech-buddy/building-a-generic-data-table-component-in-angular-5-with-material-5-8417cb8f0ce6

in hopes of producing a generic way to display arbitrary tabular data.  That example may or may not work (according to the comments), but in any case, the error I'm getting when trying to use it is

Module '"/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'CdkTableModule'.

I have two questions

1. How, if needed, would I import the CdkTableModule in Angular 5? Or is that not a thing?
2. When I look at the source code in the /@angular directory, there are lots of files, many of which are one-liners that import from some other file.  Why is the code so diffuse, and is this a good coding style that we should all emulate?  To me, as someone who wants to read the code, it's a little like trying to read a novel one PostIt note at a time in a windstorm.

Comment: Check angular material documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just try :

```
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
```

This is documented in cdk table api (the first line)
https://v5.material.angular.io/cdk/table/api